# Escaping FOR Loop in Batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I've got a batch script to utilize a command for an application to create some backups.  I've got a loop setup to run through and fetch folder names and then to run the backup operation utilizing those folder names as file names.  My loop runs great but my batch script just closes when it is finished.  I'd like to escape the loop so I can go back to a choices location I have specified.  I've seemingly been unable to escape this loop properly.  My code is below:

```
set /p work=Folder Location:
set /p staging=Location of staging-backup file:
set /p backup=Location to save backup:
@Echo off
md %backup%
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a $count=1
cd /d %staging%
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "%work%" /b/o') do (
staging-backup "%%a" "%backup%\%%a"
set /a $Count+=1
)
```

Again, this all runs great (though I can't get it to log properly but thats another battle for later) except I'd love to GOTO CHOICE at the end.  When I add it after the closing ) part of the loop, it still closes.  When I bring it inside the loop, it closes.  Do I need to wrap this loop in an if else to escape it properly?

I tried pulling the code out and pushing it to it's own bat then calling that bat with my original but no change.

```
:THREE
echo.
echo.
.\Loops.bat
echo.
echo.
GOTO CHOICE
```

This portion calls it, runs the new bat but still closes the cmd window when it is finished.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem. But could it be that you are calling a batch file from another batch file? If that's the case, you need to use the CALL command. Otherwise, it doesn't return to the original batch file.

Comment: I do not see a CHOICE label in your code at all!

Comment: the choice is further up and I didn't include the entire batch as it is quite lengthy.  Other parts go back to CHOICE without issue but aren't loops.  The others I just end with echo. echo. GOTO CHOICE and I'm back to my choice list.  Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@Echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:AGAIN
for %%a in (work staging backup) do set "%%a="
set /p "work=Folder Location: "
if not defined work goto :eof
set /p "staging=Location of staging-backup file: "
set /p "backup=Location to save backup: "
md %backup%
set /a $count=1
PUSHD %staging%
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "%work%" /b/A-D') do (
 staging-backup "%%a" "%backup%\%%a"
 set /a $Count+=1
)
POPD
GOTO AGAIN
```

Here's a revision.

The first two lines are moved to the top to turn off command-echoing prevent the variables remaining set for each run.

Then insert a label, and clear the variables.

If you reply just <kbd>Enter</kbd> to the `work` prompt, the batch terminates as `work` will be undefined (set /p leaves the variable unchanged under these circumstances - it does not clear the variable)

`PUSHD` a directory to switch temporarily to a different directory.

execute `staging-backup` in that directory. Note that if `staging-backup` is a batch, then you should use `CALL staging-backup...` (actually, you could do that with any executable - if it's a batch, you **must** do it so that `cmd` knows where to come back to at the end of the destination batch (in this case, `staging-backup.bat`)

When the `for` loop is finished, `POPD` to return to the original directory and loop back to `:AGAIN` to well - do it all again.

Comment: Thanks for the revision and update but it seems like the script is still ending after it finishes the loop and closing my cmd window instead of going back to my choices.  staging-backup is a .cmd so shouldnt have any issues running it as is without having to do a CALL beforehand.  I took the above and plopped it right in to my original batch instead of placing it in a new batch file and calling that to test that way as well to no avail.

Comment: .cmd files are batch files - you **must** use call in order that `cmd` knows where to return after the `.cmd` file ends. You say "after it finishes the loop" - what do you mean? After it invokes `staging` the very first time, or after it's executed `staging` for each directory in `work`?

Comment: It executes staging-backup for each directory properly, so it is properly going through the loop and running staging-backup on everything which is awesome.  It' s just escaping the loop afterwards allowing me to pop back to my choices to continue other parts of the script.  I'll stick call in for staging-backup to see if it'll push things in the right direction.